# Arraylist setter getter is not keeping its data after it has been set?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, path

I'm trying to set an `ArrayList` which are paths of logos of movie , each movie has a list of logos , I download all of them easily , the `studioFile` which is path of the downloaded file is collected inside `ArrayList` `studioFiles` , then I use getter setter on the `ArrayList` in order to access it from a `Fragment` later.

The problem is `ArrayList` `studioFiles` has data only during the time of downloading the logos, when I want to access it later in the `Fragment` it returns `null`

I even tried to use `SharePrefernces` with no luck.

So how can I have access to the paths of the logos after downloading the logos?

**Download the logos**

```
public class MovieIdentification {

    private void createMovie(MovieStructure ms, Movie movie) {
        boolean downloadCovers = true;

        if (!movie.getId().equals(DbAdapterMovies.UNIDENTIFIED_ID) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(movie.getId()))
            // We only want to download covers if the movie doesn't already exist
            downloadCovers = !MizuuApplication.getMovieAdapter().movieExists(movie.getId());

        if (downloadCovers) {
            String thumb_filepath = FileUtils.getMovieThumb(mContext, movie.getId()).getAbsolutePath();
            
            // Download the studio images
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(movie.getStudioUrl())) {
                JSONObject jObject = MizLib.getJSONObject(mContext, "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movie.getId() + "?api_key=" + mTmdbApiKey + "&language=en-US");
                try {
                    JSONArray production_companies = jObject.getJSONArray("production_companies");
                    ArrayList<String> studioFiles = new ArrayList<>();
                    String baseUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bronnel/resource.images.studios.coloured/master/resources/";
                    String fullUrl = "";

                   //path of downloaded logo file
                    String studioFile = ""; //path of downloaded logo file
                    for (int i = 0; i < production_companies.length(); i++) {
                        studioFile = FileUtils.getMovieStudio1(mContext, production_companies.getJSONObject(i).getString("name")).getAbsolutePath();
                        fullUrl = baseUrl + production_companies.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").replaceAll(" ", "%20") + ".png";
                        studioFiles.add(studioFile);
                        if (!MizLib.downloadFile(fullUrl, studioFile))
                            MizLib.downloadFile(fullUrl, studioFile);
                        movie.setStudiologos(studioFiles);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {}
            }
            
    }
}
```

**getter setter**

```
public class Movie {
....
    
        public ArrayList getStudiologos() { return mStudiologos; }
        
        public void setStudiologos(ArrayList studiologos) { this.mStudiologos = studiologos; }
....
}
```

**error log**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.miz.mizuu, PID: 16081
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
        at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:191)
        at com.miz.mizuu.fragments.MovieDetailsFragment.onCreate(MovieDetailsFragment.java:236)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
        at com.miz.mizuu.MovieDetails.onStart(MovieDetails.java:76)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1392)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1864)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6991)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:884)
```

Comment: not sure if i got you but  ArrayList<String> studioFiles = new ArrayList<>(); is local variable so it gone after the createMovie finish it's work

Comment: Thanks , I totally forgot about that, but I'm a beginner , so is there a workaround for this?

Comment: you very welcome  :)
2 way :
1) make this arraylist as field in your class and and use it in this method
or
2) make this class return that arrayList and use it as you like

Comment: Thanks, I just did it as field but I got the same outcome , but here is the  [class](https://pastebin.com/ezHMYQfz)  I would appreciate it of you could help me, I'm not familier with how to return the arraylist

Comment: could you add this in your consturctor 
studioFiles = new ArrayList<>();
also try to check the length of studioFiles after you finish filling it to make sure it already adding element 
using the debug mode of your idea would help also in case if there something else

Comment: I even moved it to the constructor , same result , but I just noticed something when  set breakpoint at `setStudiologos` in the getter setter class ,  `studiologos` returns the Arraylist nicely , but `mStudiologos` is `null`

Comment: now i got you
you would not need to make studioFiles as field since you save it later using that
movie.setStudiologos(studioFiles);
so you can return it to be local variable as before
there nothing mentioned in your code about mStudiologos 
looks like forget to set it

Comment: this is the [getter setter class](https://pastebin.com/tdQ0tNEE) I don't know why this happens?

Comment: the best way is to use the debug as there could be many factor did you called the getStudiologos after set it or what 
the following not issue but performance wise
move this out of the for loop
movie.setStudiologos(studioFiles);
no need to set it each iteration just do it only after filling the studiologos

Comment: maybe other part of code set it to null

Comment: Thank you , as you say it needs more debugging , I will see if there is more issues

Comment: you very welcome and good luck :)